# shortcut key cannot run as expected

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I am implementing my code in rmarkdown file in RStudio.
I have some problem when I enter Ctrl + Shift + Enter in a chunk.
I expect that this shortcut key only execute the chunk
, however the first chunk is executed first, then the chunk.

Could you tell me how to solve this trouble?

Comment: Seems kinda hard to debug without any code as reference. Maybe you can go through the `Tools` Tab in the RStudio IDE to see if your keyboard shortcuts are at default

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful. I might even help find by yourself the cause of the pb.